# Why does a put after my post, remove the last added data in my json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In my backend is something happening, which I can't understand. If I'm registering a new User, it's working fine, and I can see the new User in my JSON File, but if I'm doing a put request after that to change my own user's data he deletes the new User which I made before?

My put request from my frontend:

```js
//Changing user Data
export async function changeData(id, body) {
    try {
        await axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/users/${id}`, body, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('auth._token.local')
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My endpoint in my node backend for registering a user and changing data of a user

```js
// Register New User
server.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  console.log("register with request body", req.body)
  const {username, password, firstname, lastname, roles} = req.body

  if(!username || !password || !firstname || !lastname || !roles) {
    const status = 400
    const message = "Bad Request, make sure all properties are set in request body"
    res.status(status).json({status, message})
    return
  }

  if (req.headers.authorization === undefined || req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] !== 'Bearer') {
    const status = 401
    const message = 'Error in authorization format'
    res.status(status).json({status, message})
    return
  }

  // Send only token part to admin check
  if(!isAdmin(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1])) {
    const status = 401
    const message = 'Only permitted by admin'
    res.status(status).json({status, message})
    return
  }

  if(isAuthenticated({username, password}) === true) {
    const status = 401
    const message = 'Email and Password already exist'
    res.status(status).json({status, message})
    return
  }

  fs.readFile("./users.json", (err, file) => {
      if (err) {
        const status = 401
        const message = err
        res.status(status).json({status, message})
        return
      }

      // Get current users data
      const data = JSON.parse(file.toString())

      // Get the id of last user
      const last_item_id = data.users[data.users.length - 1].id

      //Add new user
      data.users.push({id: last_item_id + 1, username: username, password: password, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, roles: roles}) //add some data
      const writeData = fs.writeFile("./users.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err, result) => {  // WRITE
          if (err) {
            const status = 401
            const message = err
            res.status(status).json({status, message})
          }
      })
  })

  res.status(201).json({status: 201, message: "Successfully created"})
})
```

```js
// handle changing user data
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Entering Users')
  if(req.method === 'PUT' && req.url.includes("/users")) {
    if(req.body) {
      const decodedToken = jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1])
      const userList = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./users.json', 'UTF-8'))
      const userinfo = userList.users.find((user) => user.id === decodedToken.id)
     
      if(!req.body.password) {
        req.body.password = userinfo.password
      }

      // if admin made the request, he should be able to change roles
      if(req.body.roles && decodedToken.roles && decodedToken.roles.includes("admin")) {
        console.log("Able to change");
        next()
        return
      }
      req.body.roles = decodedToken.roles
    } else {
      res.status(400).json(
        {
          status: 400,
          message: "Bad request, make sure all properties are set in request body"
        }
      )
      
      return
    }
  }
  next()
})
```

The only thing i noticed is that after the register comes, the JSON file gets to a one-liner, but I don't think that this is the problem. It seems like the put works with an old user List? I'm not sure. Thanks in forward.

Comment: The error is obviously in some part of the code  you are not showing here. Because your `PUT` route doesn't modify the file at all. Depends on what the "next" request in your chain is ...

Comment: Furthermore in your `POST` route, once you have reached `fs.readFile()` you will return a status `201` in any case, because you are not awaiting what happens in the callback. You must return 201 only in the callback of `writeFile`

Comment: And using `readFileSync` in an asychronous environment is quite a bad idea because it blocks the whole server ...

Comment: Its not my backend, thats why i got the problems. In normal cases i work with NoSQL and not with json. I will take a look, thx.

Comment: Probably has something to do that your `/register` route is directly manipulating your `users.json` whereas all other routes are handled by the `jsonserver` package which doesn't know anything about the updated `users.json` after register ...